# Does a cat necessarily get sick after giving birth?

Tags: cats, health, breeding

Lots of feral cats give birth and end up being fine. Can a house cat give birth and not get ill? Do house cats always get sick after giving birth?

What are examples of diseases and disorders she could get in relation to giving birth? Must I take her to the vet if she's ready to give birth? If so, why? Wouldn't it be easier for her to have it in her home?

I'm asking this question due to the concerns of people telling me not to breed my cat while I think it's fine, but I'm worried now so someone please answer and explain why I should or shouldn't be worried.

I consider this to be a very important question, because I'm deciding to let my cat have her babies in my home.

Comment: this question dont make any sense to me at all,cats dont need to go to the vet when giving birth and they dont get sick after a normal birth,but as in every birth in any animal complications might happen that needs help from a vet.

Comment: @trondhansen I agree complications may happen but back in the day in the era of terrible medicine mortality was high in mothers giving birth (humans). From a medical journal it estimated 10.5 deaths per 1000. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1633559/ I think this is a fair question to ask, some people want to experience their pets having babies so it's good to be educated beforehand.

Comment: it was the way the question was made that i commented on and i do understand the need for information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's uncommon for cats to have complications while giving birth, sometimes you may get stillborns which is OK and does not indicate something is wrong with your cat.

You do not need to take her to the vet when she gives birth, she will want to build a nest of her own and give birth there. Some cats will have kittens on their owners bed, closet, basement etc. so be prepared to cover the things that will be difficult to clean.

Signs that your cat may have complications are:

- Straining to push more kittens but nothing comes out within 1-2 hours.
- Prolonged gestation (no kittens produced past 68 days).
- Crying, showing signs of pain.
- Bloody or green discharge BEFORE kittens come out.
- Lethargy, not eating or drinking.

It would be in the best interest of your cat if you get abdominal radiographs done when she is close to being due, the veterinarian will be able to count the kittens and let you know how many to expect.

It's important to leave mom alone while she gives birth as this is a stressful time for her, check in periodically to make sure she is OK.